# Color property of plotly bar charts not working for me

Tags: python, charts, colors, plotly

Hy
i'm trying to generate a Chart using plotly express and i just can't get my head around how to apply the correct colours to the bar. (i need a specific color for 1 bar )
[End result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVIys.png)
[So far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbEUG.png)

i have a data set with a color colum, but no matter what hex/rgb/color i send it it comes out wrong (ex aquamarine comes out as some sort of orange)

```
   PROJECT_ID KEY_NAME KEY_DESCRIPTION KEY_VALUE   KEY_PARAM KEY_GROUP  KEY_ORDER
0        6147     MinQ         Minimum     6.94%   lightblue    Chart1          1
1        6147     LowQ  Lower quartile     7.22%   lightblue    Chart1          2
2        6147     MedQ          Median      7.5%  aquamarine    Chart1          3
3        6147     UppQ  Upper quartile     7.77%   lightblue    Chart1          5
4        6147     MaxQ         Maximum    18.05%   lightblue    Chart1          6

fig = px.bar(data.sort_values('KEY_ORDER'),x='KEY_DESCRIPTION', y='KEY_VALUE', **color='KEY_PARAM'**  title = v_title,text='KEY_VALUE',labels={"KEY_DESCRIPTION": " ","KEY_VALUE": " "  })
```

tried sending all types of css colors in hex/rgb/literals.
Scowered forums for similar problems

Edit: [I managed to get the colors right folowing amance's advice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7X97.png)

But it seems the order is somehow broken down in groups of color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `color_discrete_map`. See reference [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar).

```
fig = px.bar(data.sort_values('KEY_ORDER'),
             x='KEY_DESCRIPTION',
             y='KEY_VALUE',
             color='KEY_PARAM',
             color_discrete_map='identity',
             title = v_title,
             text='KEY_VALUE',
             labels={"KEY_DESCRIPTION": " ","KEY_VALUE": " " },
             category_orders={'KEY_DESCRIPTION': data.sort_values('KEY_ORDER')['KEY_DESCRIPTION'])
```

I'd advise that you change the percentages in your KEY_VALUE column to floats (without the "%") so that each bar can be accurately plotted. You'll be able to update the format on the figure later to show it as a percentage.

Comment: Yep. thats the one. Only problem left is it seems my order is ignored when there are different colors on the bars .

Comment: @JarvisPopcorn updated with `category_orders`

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating the trace with what marker color you want

```
# Customize aspect
fig.update_traces(marker_color='rgb(158,202,225)', marker_line_color='rgb(8,48,107)', marker_line_width=1.5, opacity=0.6)
```

taken from here: https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/